# Sql Database structure for housing historical data and display changes

Tags: sql, database

Good morning,

This is more of a concept question then anything.

I am looking to design a database and interface that will track changes to the entries (in this case people) and display those changes readily.

(user experience would look something like this)

```
for user A
 Date    Category            Activity
 8/8/14  change position    position 1 -> position 2
 8/9/14  change department  department a -> department b
 ...
 ...
```

the visual experience seem like it would benefit from an E-A-V design, however i am designing the database to be easy to data mine and from my reading, i think that E-A-V is not the right way to go.

does it make sense to duplicate data just to display it?
if not, does anyone have a suggestion of how to query the history table and display? (currently using jquery and php to leverage the db...i suppose i could do something interesting from a coding perspective to get it done)

thank you for your help,

Travis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating an efficient operational database environment and a creating an 'easy-to-data mine' environment are two separate (and often opposing) goals.

Others might disagree with me but in my opinion it is best to create your database based on operational readiness (This means using your E-A-V design as mentioned above) and then worry about data transformation later. This may make it inconvenient later to transform the data to allow for easy mining but it will accomplish an incredibly important goal which is to eliminate the possibility for data error.

Once you have a good system in place where you can collect data appropriately, then you can create a warehouse or datamart environment to more conveniently extract that data.

This may sound like a lot of work but from a data integrity perspective, it is much safer than trying to create some system that is designed entirely for reporting. That's my personal opinion at least.

Comment: Thank you for your perspective. I guess I need to make sure that the UI is more important then the data mining before I commit to an EAV structure.

Answer (score 0):

(sorry cannot comment yet)

You have to analyse the data you need to persist.
if you have only a couple of tables, with no relationship, you probably don't need the database. 
In this case the database solution probably will be slower(connection/transmission/security overhead ...).

well if it's a few MBs of data, I would keep everything in one table. 
You can easily load the whole data set in memory and do what you need to do.

Comment: thanks user. this is just a small portion of the overall 'tool' that the database will provide. ultimately it will be tracking 'a lot' of different aspects of the people (training, certifications, etc). single line items on tables for the history display are easy enough to query, the big issue is providing that instant understanding of how the person is moving through the company.

Comment: so if it's a lot of data, it would make sense to replace the Category with CategoryID, and create a Category table with possibly some sub-categories. FYI: A common practise is to record the previous status only, so you don't need to specify department a -> department b. (DepartmentB is the current department)